# Hibernate mixing inheritance strategies for multi-level hierachy

Tags: java, database, hibernate, persistence, hibernate-mapping

I have the following class structure:

[image: Class diagram]

I would like to generate the following three tables with hibernate:

- PlanItem: with all its attributes
- Task: with all its attributes and its child attributes
- Stage: with all its attributes

I tried to mix the inheritancetypes but it didn't work:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.JOINED)
public abstract class PlanItem {...}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Stage extends PlanItem {...}

@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public class Task extends PlanItem {...}

@Entity
public class HumanTask extends Task {...}

@Entity
public class ProcessTask extends Task {...}

@Entity
public class CaseTask extends Task {...}
```

I already experimented with secondary tables and got more or less the desired result:

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(strategy = InheritanceType.SINGLE_TABLE)
public abstract class PlanItem {...}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable( name = "Stage" )
public class Stage extends PlanItem {...}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable( name = "Task" )
public class Task extends PlanItem {...}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable( name = "Task" )
public class HumanTask extends Task {...}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable( name = "Task" )
public class ProcessTask extends Task {...}

@Entity
@SecondaryTable( name = "Task" )
public class CaseTask extends Task {...}
```

But I was wondering if a more elegant and simple solution exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's currently not possible, see the [following issue](https://hibernate.atlassian.net/browse/HHH-7181) for further information. I think that your "hack" with using secondary tables is currently the best you can get.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. In your link they say that "The fix for this is already in place in the 5.0 codebase. I don't foresee this being addressed in 4.x.". I used the Hibernate-core-5.0.2.final.jar but it is also not possible with this version of Hibernate.

Comment: That's why it's not resolved, still not fully implemented.